# splash screen's letters are double in ionic

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am using ionic for my app but letter of splash screen are becoming double
[image]

Real image is like . What could be the reason I am using `2208x2208` resolution

[image]

Comment: Are you using capacitor or cordova?

Comment: I am using capacitor

Answer (score 0):

Splash size should be 2732*2732 located at resources/splash.png and then try generating your splash resources using this guide https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause was that I was using an image with transparent background. When I used the same logo with a white background the splashscreen appeared properly.